# Is it possible to pass parameters to js controller in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to implement a drag and drop functionality in lwc and I am getting the below code:

```html
    <template for:each={leftTask} for:item="task">
        <div class="draggable" draggable="true" key={task.taskId} 
             ondragstart={handleDragStart(task.taskId)}>{task.name}
        </div>
    </template>
```

However, it seems that lwc doesn't allow passing parameters directly into handle functions. So the above code won't work. I am wondering is it possible to pass any parameter into js handler at all? Or do I have to make a separate child component in order to handle this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can read data directly from the target:

```html
    <div data-id={task.taskId} class="draggable" draggable="true" key={task.taskId} 
      ondragstart={handleDragStart}>{task.name}</div>
```

---

```js
    function handleDragStart(event) {
        var taskId = event.target.dataset.id;
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: @sfscfox do you know of a similar solution for the `<button>` tag? When I set `data-id` and try to access it via `event.target.dataset.id`, it does not exist. dataset doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @BlondeSwan try using `event.currentTarget.dataset.id`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a lightning button then -

```html
<lightning-button data-id={rec.accId} label="my label" variant="border-filled" onclick={myFunc}></lightning-button>
```

in js file

```js
myFunc(event){
        console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
}
```

Comment: I'm using a <span data-id="whatever" onclick...>. For that, event.target.dataset.id is undefined, but event.currentTarget.dataset.id works great. thanks.